# Is there a "named" algorithm for partitioning arrays by bucket sizes

Tags: arrays, algorithm, partitioning

I'd like to take an input array and a set of possible sizes and partition the array into sub arrays that each have a count of the biggest possible bucket size that is smaller than the remaining number of items.

So given the input array...

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
```

And the sizes...

```
[10, 5, 3, 2, 1]
```

It would return an array like...

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [11, 12, 13], [14]]
```

First partitioning 10 and then 3 and then 1.

I can do this in a very clunky way using while loops and so on but I wondered if this sort of algorithm had a name of some sorts that I could research some more elegant ways of doing it.

Comment: Looks like a variation of [Coin Change](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change-making_problem) problem to me. Where the length of the input array is the sum you want to achieve and the sizes are the face values of the coins.

Comment: It sounds like a relaxed set partitioning problem

Comment: I guess along those lines, it's a relaxed bin packing problem and a relaxed knapsack problem. (all items have weight of 1, making things easier)

Comment: Oh! Yes! Thanks @AndyG I've solved for now treating it like a Coin Change problem but will definitely take a look into the Bin Packing solutions also. Thanks

Comment: Would it be valid to partition it as `[[1, 2, 3, ..., 10], [11, 12, 13, 14]]`? That is, filling the 10 element array up entirely, and then only 4 elements of the array of size 5? And what should the behavior be if the sizes were [10, 9] for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @AnandUndavia, I solved this not as an array partitioning exercise but as a Coin Change problem.

I was able to solve this using this function... (In Swift)

```
func separate(numberOfItems n: Int, bucketSizes sizes: [Int]) -> [Int] {
    var output = [Int]()
    var remaining = n

    for size in sizes {
        while remaining >= size {
            output.append(size)
            remaining -= size
        }
    }

    return output
}
```

Now with my array of sizes I can easily solve the rest of the problem that I was working on :D

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this in single loop also. Something like this is JS:

```js
var inputArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14];
var sizeArray = [10, 3, 5, 2, 1];
var outputArray = [];

sizeArray.sort(function(a, b) { return b-a}); // Sort array in decreasing order

while(sizeArray.length > 0 && inputArray.length > 0){
  var m = sizeArray[0];
  sizeArray = sizeArray.slice(1); // Pop the first element from Size Array
  if(m <= inputArray.length){
    outputArray.push(inputArray.slice(0, m)); // Extract first m elements from inputArray if its size is greater than m
    inputArray = inputArray.slice(m);
  }
}
console.log(outputArray);
```